# What exactly does the stop color % mean in css gradient?

Tags: css

What exactly does the stop color % mean in css3 gradient? Good example would be great..

Comment: might help http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients):

> **Color stops**
>
> Color stops are points along the gradient line that will have a
> specific color at that location. The location can be specified as
> either a percentage of the length of the line, or as an absolute
> length. You may specify as many color stops as you like in order to
> achieve the desired effect.
>
> If you specify the location as a percentage, 0% represents the
> starting point, while 100% represents the ending point; however, you
> can use values outside that range if necessary to get the effect you
> want.

Follow the link above for three good examples.